# Getdate() functionality returns partial day in select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query -

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Date >= DATEADD (day, -7, -getdate()) AND Date <= getdate();
```

This would return all records for each day except day 7. If I ran this query on a Sunday at 17:00 it would only produce results going back to Monday 17:00. How could I include results from Monday 08:00.

Comment: Do you really need the time ('08:00') or do you simply filter for the whole day?

Comment: try this dateadd(HOUR,8,DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM SomeWhere 
WHERE [Date] > DATEADD(HOUR,8,DATEADD(DAY, -7, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME))) --7 days back, 8 o'clock
  AND [Date] <= GETDATE(); --now
```

Comment: I get an exception "The datepart hour is not supported by date function dateadd for data type date." I'm using SQL Server btw

Comment: The cast to 'DATE' truncates the time. Forgot to cast it back to `DATETIME`. See my edits

Comment: @MitchelStuartFountaine Just a short explanation: The data type `DATE` does not know about time parts, therefore you cannot add hours...

Comment: Yea I understand better now, thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are comparing date+time, not only date.

If you want to include all days, you can trunc the time-portion from `getdate()`: you can accomplish that with a conversion to **date**:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE Date >= DATEADD (day, -7, -convert(date, getdate()) 
AND Date <= convert(date, getdate());
```

If you want to start from 8 in the morning, the best is to add again 8 hours to getdate.

```
declare @t datetime = dateadd(HH, 8, convert(datetime, convert(date, getdate())))
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE Date >= DATEADD (day, -7, -@t) AND Date <= @t;
```

NOTE: with the conversion `convert(date, getdate())` you get a datatype **date** and you cannot add hours directly to it; you must re-convert it to **datetime**.

Comment: Hi Radioleano, I just found your answer and see, that it was even better than mine. Regerettfully most questionairs do not vote on all good answers, so I'll do this now. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to remove the time. Correct?  If so then do the following.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Date >= (DATEADD (day, -7, -getdate()) AND Date DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0))
```